# Add an .egg to the python path in osx

Tags: python, path, pycharm

I'm working with PyCharm and set up a remote debugging with PyDev. Now everything is ready except when I want to debug it tells me this message in the PyCharm console:

```
Warning: wrong debugger version. Use pycharm-debugger.egg from PyCharm installation folder.
```

So I'm working in a virtualenv for Python so I logged on the the virtualenv and set the Python path to the .egg (I copied the .egg to my documents to make it easier).

```
PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:./Documents/pycharm-debug.egg"
```

Or

```
PYTHONPATH="./Documents/pycharm-debug.egg:$PYTHONPATH"
```

This didn't work, now I tried the other method which is to append the sys.path with the location of the .egg but that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Forgot to mention I'm on osx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Ok sorry about that, i misunderstood.

So you need to add the path to an environment variable, sorry. I was using a bash script for that, like this:

*pythonenv.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:./Documents/pycharm-debug.egg"
```

then call the script like this:

> source pythonenv.sh

At this point you got the env variable in your shell, remember that after you close your shell you lose the env variable.

So i don't know if OSX has an initialization script in your user folder, you should put this line in your .rc file:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:./Documents/pycharm-debug.egg"
```

So everytime you open a shell you have automatically defined the PYTHONPATH variable, some guidance here:

http://scipher.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/setting-your-pythonpath-environment-variable-linuxunixosx/

Comment: Yes I usually use pip to install my packages safely but this time I didn't need to install a package, PyCharm has a pycharm-debugger.egg in it's content and I need to add the path to that .egg file in the pythonpath. This way when I start the remote debugging it knows what to use (or at least I think that's what it meant for)

Comment: Ok sorry i got you wrong, i updated the answer. Sorry i don't know osx, i use linux, but the process is similar. I added a link that should help you on OSX. Best of luck!